# error in facebook login, the site logs in even without button pressed?why?

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I got this login page with Facebook login implemented with the javascript sdk.
It works like a charm.

The problem is that right after the login page is showed to the user the login action start, with not user interaction on the button.

I want to block this "automatic" login and wait for the user decision.

how can i make this work properly?

site:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vienes?</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body id="top">

<script>
function getUserData() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

        $.ajax({
        url: "loginSave.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {id:response.id,
          email:response.email,
          name1:response.name,
          name2:'',
          gender:response.gender} ,
        success: function (response) {
           // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)   
           window.location.href = 'index.php';
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    //SDK loaded, initialize it
    FB.init({
        appId      : '000000035339xxx',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.2'
    });

    //check user session and refresh it
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //user is authorized
            document.getElementById('load').style.display = 'none';             
            getUserData();
        } else {
        }
    });
};

//load the JavaScript SDK
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('load').addEventListener('click', function() {

    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            document.getElementById('load').style.display = 'none';
            getUserData();
                }
    }, {scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true});
}, false);
}
```

```
<div class="container text-center">
<img src="images/logoblanco.png" style="max-width: 100px;margin-top:40px">
    <h1 style="color:white;font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;font-size: 54px; margin-top:0px !important; margin-bottom:0px !important"><i>X?</i></h1>
    <p style="color:white;font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;line-height: 0.6;">XXX.</p>
</div>

<div  class="container text-center">

    <button id='load' style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom: 10px" class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook">Loging with Facebook
    </button>

</div>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```